# automatic indexing using hibernate search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

Is it possible to do automatic indexing at the time of inserting/updating a record in db using Hibernate Search. Instead of doing manually every time like running the application and also someone has to keep an eye on that so I want to do my code that part  like automatic indexing every time no need of checking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is very much possible. You can just use annotations on your Entities. Take a look at this guide:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-search-mapping-entit

Edit:

Hi. If your hibernate properties are correct, once your index is built, you don't have to index your tables manually. Each insert going through an EntityManager/HibernateFactory, will hit hibernate search and if the Entity is Indexed, it will also update the index. Have you configured your search properly? Take a look at the following links: 
http://docs.jboss.org/seam/snapshot/en-US/html/search.html  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.1/reference/en/html/search-configuration-event.html.

As the documentation clearly states

> 'By default, every time an object is inserted, updated or deleted
>   through Hibernate, Hibernate Search updates the according Lucene
>   index. It is sometimes desirable to disable that features if either
>   your index is read-only or if index updates are done in a batch way
>   (see Chapter 6, Manual indexing).'

Comment: Hi thanks for posting ur ans,actually i'm able to index 3 tables using all annotations and working totally fine but  here after indexed all 3 tables at that time again i  added a new record into db in 1st table then manually i  refreshed the application but i don't want that way i want my code to do all this automatic refresh indexing.

Comment: @user2769346, what is the actual problem you have. As baba already said, Hibernate Search does automatic index updates on entity changes, provided you use the Hibernate/JPA to make the changes. Also the automatic index updates cannot be explicitly disabled. If it is not working your you, you will need to refine your question with your concrete setup (annotated classes, Hibernate configuration, etc)